# Nativescript Typescript error property does not exist

Tags: typescript, nativescript, imagesource

Hello I am trying to get an Image element in a typescript xml page and set it's imageSource property programatically.

In the examples i've found it is done this way:

```
image = page.getViewById("id");
image.imageSource = newImageSource;
```

The issue that I am having when using typescript is

```
error 'imageSource' does not exist on type 'View'
```

I don't know how to work around that problem. any ideas?

Comment: Some reading material to help https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `image = <Image> page.getViewById('whatever');`
Should resolve the type issue. Make sure to import the image module so you have the correct class.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for. Someone in another question proposed using `var image: any = page.getViewById("whatever")` however that seemed more like working around the issue than an actual solution.

Comment: Yes, casting to `any` would be a workaround but you lose the benefits of types then :) Glad it helped out.